# Implementing the Fluent Ribbon Suite

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, fluent-ribbon

I am trying to use the Fluent ribbon suite but it's giving me error after error after error and I've not changed a single thing about it yet, I downloaded and read the entire walkthrough and search all over the web but couldn't find any help trying to get it to work.

It keeps tellling me that it's missing this and that.

And when I load it into visual studio, it won't let me view the designer because of missing assemblies, BUT THEY'RE ALL THERE. I even went through the whole damn process of unblocking every single file included in the download, it still just can't "find them". I even readded them using 'Add reference' option but nothing works.

Can someone please help me get this thing to work?

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: http://fluent.codeplex.com/ - is where I got it from.

Comment: The Fluent Ribbon Control Suite you linked to is for **WPF**, but you've tagged this question **WinForms**. Which are you using?

Comment: Sorry. I know it's WPF. I am using WPF, I just tagged it as winforms out of habbit

Answer (score 4):

Try placing following code in `app.xaml` file

```
<Application.Resources>
    <!--Attach Default Fluent Control's Theme-->
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Fluent;Component/Themes/Office2010/Blue.xaml" />
</Application.Resources>
```

This might resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

After you download the zip file, go to file property and UNBLOCK it!